# Gulp выдает ошибку с кодом Sass

Tags: css, gulp, sass

Привет!Я решил попробовать поверстать с препроцесором Sass но при компицяции кода я получаю вот такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[09:59:00] gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] app\sass\_vars.sass
Error: Invalid CSS after "$white:#ffffff": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{}"
        on line 1 of app/sass/_vars.sass
>> $white:#ffffff {}
   --------------^
```

Я посмотрел вроде как правильно задал переменные,почему же выдает ошибку и как ее исправить?

```
$white: #ffffff
$bg-gray: #292b3b
$green: #4ecb8c
$very-dark: #000000
$dark: #333333
$text-gray: #444444


$PoiretOne: 'PoiretOne'
$CabinBold: 'CabinBold'
$CabinRegular: 'CabinRegular'
$LatoBold: 'LatoBold'
$LatoLight: 'LatoLight'
$LatoRegular: 'LatoRegular'
$MontserratRegular: 'MontserratRegular'

// Customization Bootstrap  vars from "app/libs/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss"
$grid-gutter-width: 30px
$grid-columns: 12
$grid-breakpoints: (xs: 0, sm: 576px, md: 768px, lg: 992px, xl: 1200px)
$container-max-widths: (sm: 540px, md: 720px, lg: 960px, xl: 1140px)

$gutter: $grid-gutter-width
```

Comment: Поставьте пробелы между `:` и значением. `$color:<пробел>#ffffff`

Comment: Изучите синтаксис переменных. Нужны `;` в конце и убрать `:font-family`.

Comment: @Other, по-моему в `.sass` не нужно. А вот в `.scss` надо.

Comment: Обновил код в вопросе.Теперь мне выдает ошибку
`Error: File to import not found or unreadable: vars.
       Parent style sheet: D:/projects/CompanyName.com/app/sass/main.sass
        on line 1 of app/sass/main.sass
>> @import "vars";`

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov, я так понял, у вас `@import "vars";`, `;` не надо, если уж так.

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov, Читаем что пишет - нет этого файла.

Comment: Или возможно даже, что вы используете и табы и пробелы.

Comment: @entithat, может быть, не знаю, но на https://www.sassmeister.com/ выдаёт ошибку без них.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в sass нельзя использовать символы `{}`. Нельзя использовать `;` и `""` при импорте файлов также. И нужно следить за табуляцией или пробелами. То есть если вы используете пробелы, то везде должны быть пробелы. Если их два, то везде должно быть два. Иначе будет ошибка.

Валидный sass код, касательно переменных

```
$text: #000
$link: #2c5a22
$border: #e2d9d6
$buttonBg: #f500
$yellow: #fff200
$black: #000
$dark_green: #b7d1b1
$light_green: #d4e3d0
```

Пример `import` файлов

```
@import compass
@import compass/typography
@import compass/css3
@import utils/variables
```

Пример подключения шрифтов

```
@font-face 
    font-family: RobotoRegular
    src: url("../fonts/RobotoRegular/RobotoRegular.eot")
    src: url("../fonts/RobotoRegular/RobotoRegular.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype")
    src: url("../fonts/RobotoRegular/RobotoRegular.woff") format("woff"),
    src: url("../fonts/RobotoRegular/RobotoRegular.ttf") format("truetype")
    font-style: normal
    font-weight: normal
```

Пример стилизации селекторов

```
header
  height: 120px
  width: 100%
  flex: 0 0 auto
  &
    @include breakpoint($mobile)
      margin-top: 40px
```